# Visual Studio showing HTML errors

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

[image]

How to make VS not to show HTML errors?

What I've did:

- Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML (Web Forms) -> Validation -> unchecked Show Errors
- Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML -> Validation -> Enable validation set to **False**
- Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML -> Validation -> Show errors as warnings set to **False**
- Tools -> Options -> Web Essentials -> Validations -> Enable microdata validation set to **False**

After that I have restarted VS, some HTML errors disappeared (like 20-30) few are still showing.

**Note:**

I'm using Visual Studio Professsional 2015 update 3, running on Win10 x64.

I have no Resharper installed.

Extensions I have
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with accessibility checks:

```
Tools -> Options -> Web -> Accessibility Checker -> General : Enabled -> set to False
```

(or `Severity : Show Warnings -> false`)